# Why is my ElasticSeach query returning zero document?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, morelikethis

I am trying to query an AWS ElasticSearch Domain from a Lambda worker.

To do so, I am using [http-aws-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-aws-es) and the main javascript client for Elastic Search.

I query documents with the following relevant fields:

- A `ref` field - String
- A `status` field - String ENUM (`REMOVED`, `BLOCKED`, `PUBLISHED`, `PENDING`, `VERIFIED`)
- A `field` field - String Array
- A `thematics` field - String Array

What I want to achieve is:

1. Filter all documents that are not either `PUBLISHED` or `VERIFIED` or where the `ref` field is set
2. Return the best matches with my `keywwords` argument (string array) relatively to values in `field` and `thematics`
3. Sort to put documents with `PUBLISHED` status first
4. Limit the number of results to 20

I found the `more_like_this` operator, and gave it a try. I build step by step my query and the actual version, at least, doesn't return an error, but no documents are returned. It still misses the `ref` filter + #3 and #4 from above. Here is the query :

```js
  const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
      host: ELASTICSEARCH_DOMAIN,
      connectionClass: httpAwsEs,
      amazonES: {
        region: AWS_REGION,
        credentials: new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS')
      }
    })
    let keywords = event.arguments.keywords
    let rst = await client.search({
      body: {
        'query': {
          'bool': {
            'filter': {
              'bool': {
                'must_not': [
                  {
                    'term': {
                      'status': 'REMOVED'
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    'term': {
                      'status': 'PENDING'
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    'term': {
                      'status': 'BLOCKED'
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            'must': {
              'more_like_this': {
                'fields': ['field', 'thematics'],
                'like': keywords,
                'min_term_freq': 1,
                'max_query_terms': 2
              },
              'should': [
                {
                  'term': {
                    'status': 'PUBLISHED'
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }

    })
    console.log(rst)
    return rst
```

I have to upload my lambda code to debug this and it complicates debugging a lot. Since I never made ES queries before, I wanted to have at least some hints as to how to proceed with this or know if I am misusing the ES query syntax.

---

EDIT:

As requested, here is my index mapping (with JS type):

- city text (String)
- contact_email text (String)
- contact_entity text (String)
- contact_firstname text (String)
- contact_lastname text (String)
- contacts text (String list)
- country text (String)
- createdAt date (String)
- description text (String)
- editKey text (String)
- field text (String)
- id text (String)
- name text (String)
- pubId text (String)
- ref text (String)
- state text (String)
- status text (String)
- thematics text (String Array)
- type text (String Array)
- updatedAt (String)
- url text (String)
- verifyKey text (String)
- zone text (String Array)

Taken from AWS elastic search management console (index tabs > mappings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are one or two issues in your query (`should` inside `must` and `must_not` inside `filter`). Try the simplified query below instead:

```
{
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'must_not': [
        {
          'term': {
            'status.keyword': 'REMOVED'
          }
        },
        {
          'term': {
            'status.keyword': 'PENDING'
          }
        },
        {
          'term': {
            'status.keyword': 'BLOCKED'
          }
        }
      ],
      'must': [
        {
          'more_like_this': {
            'fields': [
              'field',
              'thematics'
            ],
            'like': keywords,
            'min_term_freq': 1,
            'max_query_terms': 2
          }
        }
      ],
      'should': [
        {
          'term': {
            'status.keyword': 'PUBLISHED'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for putting me on the right track. You saved me a lot of time. Cheers!

Comment: It turns out that the `must_not` is not considered in the query results. I get documents with forbidden values (e.g. status: 'BLOCKED'). If I replace it by `filter`, I have no result being returned. The ES version is 6.2. I also tried to replace the `more_like_this` with a `match_phrase` without success. Any suggestion? Should I open another question? Thanks again

Comment: Can you show your index mapping? I might know the reason

Comment: I need the mapping that comes from ES, i.e. the one you get from `GET your-index-name/_mapping`

Comment: The ES endpoint is protected by cognito. I'll use my lambda to get the mappings. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: At some point you might want to consider reading this: https://www.elastic.co/aws-elasticsearch-service

Comment: I'm captive of AWS ecosystem since I used amplify and their @searchable directive to generate the ES stack. It's very expensive, and certainly inferior in terms of features. However, I would have to modify a dynamoDB trigger to replicate new records on ES as well as my search query (on top of an app Sync graphQL api). I'm on a very tight schedule and so far, my ES experience is nothing but pain.

Comment: Ok, let's see that mapping then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214739/discussion-between-billybobbonnet-and-val).

Comment: Go ahead, try again the updated query (see that `status` has been replaced by `status.keyword`)

Comment: Finally, it works. Thank you very much for your help and patience. I would upvote you twice if I could :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!